# How can I programmatically add model coefficients to the intercept term with R?

Tags: r

Running regressions with categorical variables allows you to essentially calculate group means using the resulting intercept and coefficients (and it's a common replacement for ANOVA analysis). For instance, in this example predicting age by marital status, the intercept shows the mean age for unmarried people, while the intercept + the married coefficient shows the mean age for married people:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Make a bunch of two-level factors
gss_clean <- gss_cat %>% 
  filter(race != "Other") %>% 
  mutate(relig = recode(relig, Protestant = "Protestant", .default = "Not Protestant"),
         marital = recode(marital, Married = "Married", .default = "Not married"),
         race = fct_drop(race)) 

# Super simple model
model_1 <- lm(age ~ marital, data = gss_clean)

# Average age for unmarried people
coefficients(model_1)[1]
#>    46.68678

# Average age for married people
coefficients(model_1)[1] + coefficients(model_1)[2]
#>    49.37324

# Verify
gss_clean %>% 
  group_by(marital) %>% 
  summarize(avg_age = mean(age, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   marital     avg_age
#>   <fct>         <dbl>
#> 1 Not married    46.7
#> 2 Married        49.4
```

This also works in models with interactions, as long as you add the correct coefficients. In this situation, this combination of coefficients provides the means for different groups in the data:

- Black, not married: intercept
- Black, married: intercept + married
- White, not married: intercept + race
- White, married: intercept + married + race + (married * race)

```r
# Model with interactions
model_2 <- lm(age ~ marital + race + marital * race, data = gss_clean)

# Black, not married
coefficients(model_2)[1]
#>    42.93019

# Black, married
coefficients(model_2)[1] + coefficients(model_2)[2]
#>    46.40878

# White, not married
coefficients(model_2)[1] + coefficients(model_2)[3]
#>    47.73707

# White, married
coefficients(model_2)[1] + coefficients(model_2)[3] + coefficients(model_2)[4]
#>    46.20407

# Verify
gss_clean %>% 
  group_by(marital, race) %>% 
  summarize(avg_age = mean(age, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   marital [?]
#>   marital     race  avg_age
#>   <fct>       <fct>   <dbl>
#> 1 Not married Black    42.9
#> 2 Not married White    47.7
#> 3 Married     Black    46.4
#> 4 Married     White    49.7
```

While it's kind of okay to do this by hand, I'm hoping to find a more generalizable way of properly adding these coefficients without needing to remember all the coefficient indexes. This is especially helpful in more complicated models with 3-way interactions, like this:

```r
# Model with lots of interactions
model_3 <- lm(age ~ marital + race + relig + 
                marital * race + marital * relig + race * relig +
                marital * race * relig, 
              data = gss_clean)

# Black, not married, not protestant
coefficients(model_3)[1]
#>    38.56587

# Everything else: so much manual adding :(
```

Is there some built-in method for adding the appropriate coefficients to the intercept in R, or is there some simple approach for doing this that doesn't involve lines and lines of `coefficients(model)[n] + coefficients(model)[m] + ...`?

Comment: Your last model can be simplified to `lm(age ~ marital * race * relig, data = gss_clean)`. This will include all interactions.

Comment: True. I just had them all in there so I could keep track of indexes easier and remember that 1 is marital, 4 is marital * race, etc.

Comment: Is this not a job for `expand.grid` and `predict`?

Comment: Also, the coefficients all have names, so you don't have to remember the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
pred_means <- function(model, continuous = "mean") {
    terms <- purrr::map(model$model, unique)[-1]
    if(continuous == "mean") {
      cont <- !purrr::map_lgl(terms, is.factor)
      terms[cont] <- map(terms[cont], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    pred_data <- expand.grid(terms)
    pred_data$mean <- predict(model, newdata = pred_data)
    pred_data
}
```

By default, this function will calculate the means for all levels, while taking the mean of any continuous predictors. But, you could also change the argument for `continuous` to anything other than `"mean"`, and it will give you the mean for all the observed values of the continuous predictor variables. Here's a few examples

```
pred_means(model_1)
      marital     mean
1 Not married 46.68678
2     Married 49.37324

pred_means(model_2)
      marital  race     mean
1 Not married White 47.73707
2     Married White 49.68266
3 Not married Black 42.93019
4     Married Black 46.40878

pred_means(model_3)
      marital  race          relig     mean
1 Not married White     Protestant 51.72343
2     Married White     Protestant 51.26028
3 Not married Black     Protestant 44.77419
4     Married Black     Protestant 47.38913
5 Not married White Not Protestant 44.39232
6     Married White Not Protestant 47.81385
7 Not married Black Not Protestant 38.56587
8     Married Black Not Protestant 42.80000
```

And an example with a continuous predictor

```
model_4 <- lm(age ~ tvhours + marital + race + relig + 
                marital * race + marital * relig + race * relig +
                marital * race * relig, 
              data = gss_clean)

pred_means(model_4)

   tvhours     marital  race          relig     mean
1 11.21739 Not married White     Protestant 60.97432
2 11.21739     Married White     Protestant 61.58266
3 11.21739 Not married Black     Protestant 52.50899
4 11.21739     Married Black     Protestant 56.96309
5 11.21739 Not married White Not Protestant 54.22298
6 11.21739     Married White Not Protestant 57.80670
7 11.21739 Not married Black Not Protestant 46.84537
8 11.21739     Married Black Not Protestant 52.43112

head(pred_means(model_4, "all"))
  tvhours     marital  race      relig     mean
1      12 Not married White Protestant 61.87577
2       2 Not married White Protestant 50.35732
3       4 Not married White Protestant 52.66101
4       1 Not married White Protestant 49.20548
5       3 Not married White Protestant 51.50917
6       0 Not married White Protestant 48.05364
```

Comment: Oooh, this is a really nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help!